# How to add attributes to a shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

Reading the codex, I have:

```
function btn_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'button',
    ), $atts );

    return '<a class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '">' . $content . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'button', 'btn_shortcode' );
```

In the WYSIWIG I put `[button class="btn btn-lg btn-default"]Learn More[/button]` and it outputs as I want it to, but I want to write my shortcode to do this:

```
[button href="foo" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"]Learn More[/button]
```

How would I modify my function to allow this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to add another element to the array (and then output it):

```
function btn_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'button',
        'href'  =>  '#'
    ), $atts );

    return '<a class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '" href="' . esc_attr($a['href']) . '">' . $content . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'button', 'btn_shortcode' );
```

**//EDIT:**

In order to add user-defined styles you also just have to add another element to the array:

```
function btn_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'button',
        'href'  =>  '#',
        'style' =>  ''
    ), $atts );

    return '<a class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '" href="' . esc_attr($a['href']) . '" style="' . esc_attr($a['style']) . '">' . $content . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'button', 'btn_shortcode' );
```

Here's a usage example:

`[button href="foo" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:50px; background-color: #999"]Learn More[/button]`

**//EDIT2:**

You can add different style attributes to the shortcode and then output them all inside the style attribute of the HTML tag, but this will limit the custom CSS only to these predefined attributes and you also must have some predefined values for each of them in case the user leaves them empty.
If some of them are left empty and you have no predefined values you might end up with something like this - `<a href="#foo" class="button" style="font-weight:; margin-top: 20px; background-color:;"`

```
function btn_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'button',
        'href'  =>  '#',
        'background-color' =>  '#999',
        'font-weight' => 'normal',
        'margin-top' => '10px'

    ), $atts );

    return '<a class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '" href="' . esc_attr($a['href']) . '" style="font-weight:' . esc_attr($a['font-weight']) . '; background-color' . esc_attr($a['background-color']). '; margin-top:' . esc_attr($a['margin-top']) . ';">' . $content . '</a>';
}
```

Here's a usage example:

`[button href="foo" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" font-weight="bold" margin-top="50px" background-color="#999"]Learn More[/button]`

Comment: How would you do styles though?

Comment: By styles you mean something like `[button href="foo" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" style="font-weight:bold"]Learn More[/button]` or something else (if something else, please provide an example)?

Comment: Yeah, like let's say we had font-weight, margin-top, background-color as examples.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. For each new attribute you require you just have to add another element to the array (and use it later of course).

Comment: so in the array I add `'background-color' => 'whatever'` but how do I add that into the style? Idk I'm a bit confused still.

Comment: So, you need multiple attributes for different style properties and not just one where you add pure CSS?

Comment: I'd like to know how, as another method to doing this. Your method is great. I know css so I can go in there. I feel like if there were multiple attributes for different styles it'd be easier for someone, like a client, to go in and make changes that would be easier for them to modify.

Comment: @Darren Bachan - Take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: This would require the user to still have to type things out in "style", here's how I was hoping the shortcode would look `[button class="foo" background-color="#000000" margin-top="20px;"]`

Comment: `[button class="btn" style=""background-color:#e6e7e8; margin-top:100px;"]` I put some test values on here, based on your code, but it doesn't read them and takes the default values.

Comment: @Darren Bachan - Did you look at the section **//EDIT2:** where the new code does the exact same thing?

Comment: Ah, idk how I missed that, yeah okay this works. Amazing.

Comment: it's working for me. upvote from my side.