# How to take parameters from a function and make them editable as attributes in a shortcode

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I want to make shortcodes easily editable for the user, how can I modify this shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'show_news', 'news_query' );

function news_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => 'news',
    );
    $news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $news_query->have_posts() ) :
        $html_out = '<article>';
        while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) :
            $news_query->the_post();
            // Do stuff with each post here
            $html_out .= '<div class="news-item"><div class="meta-date">' . Date('m/y') . '</div><div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4></div><div class="meta-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div></div></div>';
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        $html_out = "Nothing to show";
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

so that it would work with this shortcode [recent_posts type="news" posts_per_page="3"]

Comment: This question here might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232197/how-to-add-attributes-to-a-shortcode The example on the `add_shortcode` reference page shows how to pass attributes too https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/. Also, you would need to change `add_shortcode( 'show_news', 'news_query' );` to `add_shortcode( 'recent_posts', 'news_query' );` if you want to use `recent_posts` shortcode

Comment: Yeah I made that one, but one is `$atts` and the other is `$args`, how could I return the `$args`? In the page you linked `esc_attr` is used but `esc_args` doesn't work.

Comment: There is no `esc_args` function. Also, if you look at the links in my previous comment, you need to pass the `$atts` in the callback function. You will extract the individual attributes as done in the `btn_shortcode` function in the answer here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232197/how-to-add-attributes-to-a-shortcode . You will then use attributes in your `$args` array. If you provide your updated code with what you did it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are asking how to pass parameters to a shortcode. This can be done with the function [`shortcode_atts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts), which has two required parameters: an array of valid parameters and their defaults, and the attributes of the shortcode that is being passed. You would use it like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'wpse232385_show_news', 'wpse232385_news_query' );

function wpse232385_news_query ($atts) {
$news_atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'category_name' => 'news' ),
    $atts );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $news_atts['posts_per_page'],
    'category_name' => $news_atts['category_name'],
);
$news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
...
}
```